# Add a scrollbar to a <div> element

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I want to add a scrollbar to my `secundary` `div`, I added the `width` and `height`:

```css
#primary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

#secundary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="secundary">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

I tried with `overflow: scroll` property, but I can't see any scrollbar in the `secundary` `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage values for `height` only works if the parent element have a fixed `height` value. Currently, your `#secundary` element is `body`'s child, and the `body`'s height is set to `auto`- which is the default value - and that makes `body`'s height vary according to the height of its children.

Either you define a fixed height value for `#secundary`, or for your `body`.

An example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvhe70y/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#primary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

#secundary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="secundary">
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text text
</div>
```

There needs to be a "overflow" of content:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

https://output.jsbin.com/sugelod

```
#primary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#secundary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: But... There is no scrollbar.

Comment: Because there is no content inside primary and secundary div

Comment: Exactly, so it doesn't really solve the problem... no?